# What is natural way of saying I am/was suffering from fever?

Tags: phrase-requests

I know that the expression I have written is completely correct, but it does not feel very natural and I have never seen it being used in movies etc. Should it be something like "I picked up a fever"?

Comment: "Not enough cowbell."

Comment: "... suffering from fever" appeared 1,710,000 times on the web -- if you doubted it. What was the question? Or is it a non-Q?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In addition to the provided suggestions, I might also say,

- I have (got) a fever.
- I was down with a fever.
- I've come down with a fever.
- I'm running a fever. (I suspect that this is usually said of somebody else.)
- I'm running a temperature.

Comment: Why 'a' before fever?

Comment: Is "running a fever/temperature" more common than "having a fever"? What's more commonly used?

Answer (score 9):

"I've had a fever (for the past three days / three weeks / etc.)" is all that's necessary. It's also natural and idiomatic. "I've been suffering from ..." is emotional and overly dramatic, but also natural and idiomatic. It's a style choice.

Answer (score 9):

I am feeling a tad **feverish** after being around all those sick kids.

> fe·ver·ish
>   adjective
>   1.
>   having fever.

Comment: This is technically correct, but rarely used.

Comment: I heard the word *befevered* once, but I can't remember where.

Comment: It might be easier to remember than a complicated idiomatic expression like "I'm running a fever" or "I've come down with a fever." That's my thinking.

Comment: Something like “I was feverish for several days” doesn’t sound odd or unusual to me at all; this seems a pretty natural phrasing to me (British, lived for some years in NE US/Canada).

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, if I hear "I have fever" or "I am suffering from fever" without "a" preceding it, I tend to think it is a disease, like Dengue Fever or Yellow Fever, rather than just an elevated body temperature, which is more likely a ***symptom*** of an infection or virus.

> I would say, "I'm running a temperature" or "I'm running a fever"

Comment: Is "running a fever/temperature" more common than "having a fever"?